# Combine linq queries together

Tags: c#, linq

I have to linq queries which have only a small difference between them. I am trying to merge them both.

```
.Where(i => 
    !i.Username.StartsWith("e-") &&
    i.SSN != null && i.SSN != "" && 
    i.DisplayName != null && i.DisplayName != "" && 
    i.LastName != null && i.LastName != "" && 
    i.FirstName != null && i.FirstName != "")
.ToList();
```

and the other one is

```
.Where(i => 
    !i.Username.StartsWith("e-") && 
    i.SSN != null && i.SSN != "" && 
    i.DisplayName != null && i.DisplayName != "" && 
    i.LastName != null && i.LastName != "" && 
    i.FirstName != null && i.FirstName != "" && 
    i.WhenChanged.HasValue && i.WhenChanged.Value > DateTime.UtcNow.Add(_whenChangedTimeSpan))
.ToList();
```

as you can see only the last item in where clause is different. Can they both be merge together?

Comment: What do you mean by merging them? Avoiding code duplication?

Comment: Make the second one only the last item and the input the first.  Running the second will automatically run the first.

Comment: Since you and all those conditions together you can do multiple calls to `Where` with each condition.  Then you can have the last one nested in an `if` to determine when you want to include it.

Comment: I've updated my answer according to your comment @jdweng.

Comment: Note that it depends on the type of LINQ (more specifically: the Entity Framework version, if applicable) whether this code is efficient. You may have to replace all these null checks by composing the predicate by a predicate builder. Please always use more specific LINQ tags, if appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choice of either of the Linq Queries is based on a "condition", you could do the following.

```
var result = list.Where(
                i => !i.Username.StartsWith("e-")
                     && i.SSN != null && i.SSN != ""
                     && i.DisplayName != null && i.DisplayName != ""
                     && i.LastName != null && i.LastName != ""
                     && i.FirstName != null && i.FirstName != ""
                     && (condition? 
                     i.WhenChanged.HasValue && i.WhenChanged.Value > DateTime.UtcNow.Add(_whenChangedTimeSpan) 
                     : true)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like this.

Create a method to do the common check

```
bool CommonCheck(TypeOfYourVariable i)
{
    return !i.Username.StartsWith("e-") &&
        i.SSN != null && i.SSN != "" &&
        i.DisplayName != null && i.DisplayName != "" &&
        i.LastName != null && i.LastName != "" &&
        i.FirstName != null && i.FirstName != "";
}
```

Use it like this:

```
// first
.Where(i => CommonCheck(i))
.ToList();

// secpmd
.Where(i => CommonCheck(i) &&
    i.WhenChanged.HasValue && i.WhenChanged.Value > DateTime.UtcNow.Add(_whenChangedTimeSpan))
.ToList();
```

**Update**, or you can do this:

```
var firstQueryResult = yourInput.Where(i => 
    !i.Username.StartsWith("e-") &&
    i.SSN != null && i.SSN != "" &&
    i.DisplayName != null && i.DisplayName != "" &&
    i.LastName != null && i.LastName != "" &&
    i.FirstName != null && i.FirstName != "" &&
).ToList();

var secondQueryResult = firstQueryResult
    .Where(i=> i.WhenChanged.HasValue && i.WhenChanged.Value > DateTime.UtcNow.Add(_whenChangedTimeSpan))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Side note: custom methods that are called in LINQ statements don't work with Entity Framework. If you need to use this in EF, use the solution added in the update section of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since the second query is just a subset of the first query, first execute the first query and then run the filter over that result:

```
var result = (...).Where(
i => !i.Username.StartsWith("e-")
&& i.SSN != null && i.SSN != ""
&& i.DisplayName != null && i.DisplayName != ""
&& i.LastName != null && i.LastName != ""
&& i.FirstName != null && i.FirstName != ""
).ToList();

var filteredResult = result.Where(i.WhenChanged.HasValue && i.WhenChanged.Value > DateTime.UtcNow.Add(_whenChangedTimeSpan)).ToList();
```

This will run the query only once on the database, and will do the second part in memory on your app server.

Comment: there's no need to call `.ToList()` here - if you omit it then it will all only be executed on the database.

Comment: Yea you're right. Doesn't really make a difference for OP's question though, unless he really wants to merge on database level.